# How can I extract images from Word file(doc, docx) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word, mammoth

I am trying to extract contents from Word file with Node.js and I have already got text with mammoth.
But the image extraction doesn't work well.
How can I complete it?
I am working on Node.js.

```
 mammoth.extractRawText({ path: req.file.path })
  .then(async (result) => {
        const images = result.messages.filter(message => message.type === "image");
            images.forEach((image, index) => {
                const { contentType, content } = image;
                const extension = contentType.split("/")[1];
                fs.writeFileSync(`image_${index}.${extension}`, content, 'binary');
            });
       }
    )
```

Comment: Explain what "the image extraction doesn't work well" means

Comment: I tried by myself and resolve that problem, but I have another challenge.
Extracted image format is EMF and needs to be formatted to png or jpeg.
And also I should save this data to mongodb.
Which method would be best in this case?

Comment: If you can post the solution here as an answer, you may be able to help other people with the same problem

Comment: New questions should be raised in a new post